# Complexity of the Schönhage–Strassen algorithm

Tags: complexity

In the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage%E2%80%93Strassen_algorithm), the complexity is listed as $O(n \cdot \log (n) \cdot \log (\log (n)))$, where $n$ is the number of bits.

Would the real bound be given by setting $n=\frac{b}{w}$, where $b$ is the number of bits and $w$ is the word length in the computer? i.e., if I assume that numbers of size $\log (n)$ can be multiplied in $O(1)$ time, then can two numbers of size $r \log (n)$ be multiplied in $O(r \cdot \log (r) \cdot \log( \log (r)))$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you are actually asking is for the performance of the Schönhage–Strassen algorithm in the unit cost RAM (rather than its bit complexity). This is covered in Fürer's paper [How Fast Can We Multiply Large Integers on an Actual Computer?](https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.1811), likely written with similar motivation to yours.